# Magento 1.9.x migration on VPS error 403

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I have to migrate the site in magento 1.9.4.3, multilingual, from shared hosting to VPS. On shared hosting I use cPanel, while on VPS I will use Plesk.
After a successful transfer trial I realized an error.

I state that in the root of the site I have created folders with the name of the language code of the site where inside, except for the sitemap.xml of the site with this structure:

```
/en/sitemap/sitemap.xml
/it/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

With cPanel I have no problems, instead on the server and plesk, if I click on the site's home or on the logo, the error 403 appears; but by renaming the folders the error disappears.

I would like to eliminate this error, and while ***keeping the folders "en" and "it"*** where I store the sitemaps to be sent to search console.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear but I'm sure before installing Magento you need to setup your Apache or Nginx or whatever server (then PHP and MySQL as well) so that you see that www.yoursite.com shows "Hello world!" from index.php. Check [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/apache.html) for example, the instructions apply to Magento 1 as well.
I suggest you tune the settings in server configuration files no matter what Plesk says.

Comment: I don't know what is not clear, the site can be seen, as we can also see "hello world". The question I pose is different. Why the direcotories named with "it" and "en" identical to the language view code, on one server don't give problems but on another give me error 403?
At most, it should see the contents of the folder. So, could it be an htaccess problem?

Comment: What is your document root (accordingly to Apache settings)? Have you checked the permissions of these directories? (provided they are within the document root). Depending on your configuration .htaccess should reflect these codes like this: `SetEnvIf Host it.store.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=it` and `SetEnvIf Host en.store.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en`